# 403 Forbidden Error When Uploading SSL Certificate to OwnCloud on Docker

Tags: docker, permissions, ssl-certificate, owncloud

I'm encountering a 403 Forbidden error when trying to upload an SSL certificate to my OwnCloud server running in a Docker container. I've taken several steps to resolve this without success, and I'm looking for assistance to identify and fix the underlying issue.

89.7.216.10 - - [07/Dec/2023:11:49:12 +0000] "POST /settings/admin/certificate HTTP/1.1" 403 749 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Issue:
When attempting to upload an ASCII-encoded PEM SSL certificate through the OwnCloud admin interface, I receive a 403 Forbidden error. The error message suggests an issue with the file format or encoding, but I've verified the certificate is correctly formatted.

Steps taken:
Adjusted file permissions of the OwnCloud directory to www-data:www-data.
Restarted the Docker container after changing permissions.
Checked .htaccess in the OwnCloud directory, which doesn't seem to have any restrictions that could lead to a 403 error.
Reviewed Apache configuration files (apache2.conf, default.conf) within the Docker container for any potential misconfigurations.